# Convert special chars (Danish: æøå) on jQuery AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use jQuery to do AJAX calls. But specialchars like ÆØÅ (danish letter) comes out as garble. Is there an easy way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably an encoding problem. Are you using UTF-8? This is the recommended practice. First verify that the server actually returns UTF-8 encoded data. Use a non-Ajax call to verify this. Firebug could help a lot.

Then make sure that the hosting page (the one from which the Ajax call is made) is also UTF-8 encoded:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```